# Angular expression inside style attribute don't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, internet-explorer-10

I have angular 1.0.6 (I know it's old) and I have style attribute with expressions:

```
<li style="background-color: {{item.color}}">
   <span style="color: {{item.color | contrastColor}}">{{item.label}}</span>
</li>
```

It work fine but not for IE (The app need to work for >IE10). When I open Developer tool the style attribute is not present. I've try to create custom style directive (because I tought that IE remove invalid attribute before Angular can read it) but with this simple code, I've got an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` from jquery (tested on google chrome) because in my case item.color can be null

```
.directive("logStyle", function() {
    // logStyle directive
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           element.css(scope.$eval(attrs.logStyle));
        }
    };
});
```

How can I make it work. I know that there is ngStyle but it's not quite what I need.

Comment: can you create a plunker or jsfiddle, I'd like to see it across browsers.

Comment: using .css() read requires .css(propertyName), and set requires element.css(propertyName, newValue), it seems you are trying to read rather than to set

Comment: @EliteOctagon you can also use css with object. I wanted to parse and create object using $eval. Maybe I should use JSON `{color:  item.color}` as attribute value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, try this but I'm not sure if I fully understand what your trying to do

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-style="{'background-color': item.color}">
        <span ng-style="{ 'color': (item.color | contrastColor) }">{{ item.label }}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Edited the html, couldn't test this on IE last night so had to wait until today. IE seemingly doesn't like the style attribute with {{ }} binding inside so it deletes it from the DOM. I found this issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2186 and there is a plunkr with the fix given.

Comment: Don't work, got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'exp' of undefined`

Comment: Additionaly `color: {{item.color | contrastColor}}` return parse error while using ng-style.

Comment: Are you trying to filter by contrastColor?

Comment: it's custom filter that return white or black depend on the color.

Comment: You can use `ng-style="{backgroundColor: section.color}"` no need to wrap in `{{ }}`, also why did you put angular js code, I have it I've ask about style (I didn't ask how to create a constrastColor filter), also why you showing me `$scope.items` it was not my question. I've didn't include that code in my question because it was not relevant.

Answer (score 4):

For me changing `style` to `ng-attr-style` solved the issue. Tested in IE and Chrome. Hope this helps someone else.

You can use `{{ }}` like this:

```
ng-attr-style="color:{{entity.status | statusColor}};"
```

Answer (score 2):

IE browser is not able to parse angular expression with `style` attribute so You should use `ng-style` instead of `style` to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

changing style to ng-attr-style resolves the issue and works fine in all the browsers